# Sending data of ajax by another ajax to controller in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I want to know is that possible to send data from one ajax by another ajax or not?

Sounds confusing I know, but here is explanation:

I have payment method where it gets data and handling them by Ajax (**unfortunately the creators of this API limited their code a lot**) so even if i try to add input request in controller code of that Ajax nothing will work, that's why I need to make another Ajax to handle that input request.

Lets explain more by codes:

`controller`

```
public function orderspayonline(Request $request, $id){
        error_log('masuk ke snap token dri ajax');
        $midtrans = new Midtrans;
        //products data + user info etc.

        //here magic happens
        try
        {
            $snap_token = $midtrans->getSnapToken($transaction_data);
            echo $snap_token;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {   
          return $e->getMessage;
        }
    }
```

If I add anything (I mean anything) in that `try{` part it will stop functioning and return error! `even I tried to redirect back my users except echoing token code that gave error as well. *So it seems I really don't have any option here but to create new function and Ajax*.

`JavaScript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.pay-button').click(function (event) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
      });
    event.preventDefault();
    // $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    var prdfoId = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{url("orderspayonline")}}/'+encodeURI(prdfoId),
          type: "POST",
          cache: false,

          success: function(data) {
            var resultType = document.getElementById('result-type');
            var resultData = document.getElementById('result-data');

            function changeResult(type,data){
              $("#result-type").val(type);
              $("#result-data").val(JSON.stringify(data));
            }

            snap.pay(data, {
              onSuccess: function(result){
                changeResult('success', result);
                console.log(result.status_message);
                console.log(result);
                $("#payment-form").submit();
              },
              onPending: function(result){
                changeResult('pending', result);
                console.log(result.status_message);
                $("#payment-form").submit();
              },
              onError: function(result){
                changeResult('error', result);
                console.log(result.status_message);
                $("#payment-form").submit();
              }
            });
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The part I need to manipulate is `snap.pay(data, {` where results gets back.

Currently they are return in console and disappear in a sec as the result of `echo $snap_token;` in my controller.
**I have tried to get them in hidden input**, but as I mentioned I cannot get results because I can't change my `try` code, even I tried to get them after `catch` part closed, the same thing happens **Error**.

#### Question

1. How can I get my results in controller?

*I need to update my database with that results.*

Thanks.

Comment: I think the main question here is "why does my controller error whenever I edit the code?". Can you show us what edits you tried to the `try { ..` code and what errors you got? Also, the `payment-form` is being submitted by your JS, where does it send the data?

Comment: @user1491032 i tried this in `try` `$status_message ="$request->input('status_message'); dd($status_message);` which was related to hidden input i appended in my `on success` code (when didn't work i removed it to default ones which is in my question), `payment-form is being submitted by your JS, where does it send the data` it sends data to third party website something like PayPal but local one.

Comment: lose the `"` from `... ="$request ...`

Comment: This code looks like it is just requesting a token from your server, sending that to `snap.pay`, and if successful it is submitting the payment form. What else do you want it to do?

Comment: `"` that was my mistake typing it here, `for answering your second comment`  i want to get the results of `on success` in my controller that's all i want. (i need to pass them in controller.

Comment: ......Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you have two choices.

1. Add another client-side AJAX call within the `snap.pay` function
2. Redirect the submission of `payment-form` towards your own app and then do the onward submission from the server-side.

**Option 1:**

```
function serverSubmit(d) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
    });

    $.ajax({
      url: '{{url("newroute")}}',
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      data: d
     });
};
```

Then amend `snap.pay` to submit, e.g.

```
snap.pay(data, {
    onSuccess: function(result){
        changeResult('success', result);
        console.log(result.status_message);
        console.log(result);
        serverSubmit(result); // <----------
        $("#payment-form").submit();
    }
    ...
```

You may want to encrypt the data if it is sensitive, and you may want to decide not to submit the form if you don't get a successful result from the serverSubmit. You may also want to submit supplemental data beyond the `result`, but this is a start.

**Option 2**

Change the `<form id="payment-form...` `action` to `{{url('newroute')}}`

In your controller add a new method and map a `post` `newroute` to it.

```
public function new_method(Request $request)
{
      $data = $request->validate(...);
      YourModel::create($data); //however you want to save it

      $url = 'old_form_submit_URL';

      $options = array(
          'http' => array(
              'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
               'method'  => 'POST',
               'content' => http_build_query($data)
          )
      );

      $context  = stream_context_create($options);
      $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

      if ($result === FALSE) { /* There was an error */ }

 }
```